# Mi service Provider not found

Tags: laravel

Necesito desarrollar un *serviceProvider* propio, en mi archivo `app.php` lo cargo de la siguiente forma:

```
...
 * Package Service Providers...
 */
Edelrojas\Access\ServiceProvider::class,//este es el service provider.
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
...
```

El directorio donde tengo el paquete (aunque lo he probado en varios directorios) y por tanto el *ServiceProvider* esta en:

> vendor\edelrojas\access\src

Y el código básico que tengo en el *serviceProvider*:

```
    namespace EdelRojas\Access;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as IlluminateServiceProvider;

    class ServiceProvider extends IlluminateServiceProvider
    {
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }                                                                                                  }
```

No encuentro que es lo que me falta. si declaro el *ServicesProvider* dentro de `App\Providers` no lanza el error, pero necesito declararlo fuera pk es parte de un paquete con routes, controllers, etc; independientes a las del proyecto.

El error es el que se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Registraste esto: `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,` en tu array de providers cierto?

Comment: si, en la primera muestra del código lo publique, y declare mi servicesProvider antes de App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class.

Comment: Muestranos entonces donde y como invocas a la clase que registraste en el service provider

Comment: realmente no estoy llamando al service provider todavia, ese error me lo lanza en cualquier url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos solucione el problema añadiendo:

```
"Edelrojas\\Access\\": "packages/edelrojas/access/src"
```

Al `composer.json` de la raíz del proyecto, en el *autoload*. En mi caso quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Edelrojas\\Access\\": "packages/edelrojas/access/src"
    }
},
```

Después desde la raíz del proyecto ejecutar:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Y ya reconoce el service provider.